# Don't collapse ExtJS Menu when clicked outside it

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, mouseevent

In my application , I show a ExtJS menu when clicked on a button. This menu gets collapsed when I click outside it.But my requirement it this menu should not collapse when clicked outside it.

I debugged in ExtJS files, there is a mousedown Event in GlobalEvents [see here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.GlobalEvents)  which gets fired and it collapse this menu. How can I change or override this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to `return false;` in your menu `beforehide` event handler.

Comment: Already tried . Not working.

Comment: Just checked in fiddle, works for me.

Comment: so add a fiddle that showing your issue, you did't gave us any code.

Answer (score 0):

As fast workaround you can to `return false;` in your menu `beforehide` event handler.

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1atq)

Comment: ??????? Then you can't hide the menu ever again at all. Thats not even a workaround..

Comment: @Xatenev Yes, you have to hide it manually when you need it. I do not provide solution, just pointed out direction.